# How to allocate more space to Option's text in SettingsPane?

Tags: gluon-mobile

If I create a settings pane and add `new DefaultOption(...)` to it with an icon and text then the controller on the right takes more space than it needs and trims the text in the middle.

```
Option<BooleanProperty> antiAliasingOption = new DefaultOption<>(MaterialDesignIcon.BLUR_OFF.graphic(),
        "Anti-aliasing", "Toggle anti-Aliasing", null, new SimpleBooleanProperty(), true);
```

[image]

You can see that there's a lot of space (red line) for the toggle button which is not used and the text is cut off. I want the controls to be justified to the right like in a border pane where the center takes all unallocated space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [Scenic View](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) to inspect the Settings control, you will find that for every Option there is an `HBox` that contains a left `HBox` for the icon, a central `VBox` for the text and a right `HBox` for the editor.

[image: scenic view]

All these containers have style classes, so an easy way to modify any of them on runtime is by using lookups.

As for the right HBox, you can look for the `secondary-graphic` and then set the preferred width:

```
public BasicView(String name) {
    super(name);

    Option<BooleanProperty> antiAliasingOption = new DefaultOption<>(MaterialDesignIcon.BLUR_OFF.graphic(),
    "Anti-aliasing", "Toggle anti-Aliasing", null, new SimpleBooleanProperty(), true);

    SettingsPane settings = new SettingsPane(FXCollections.<Option>observableArrayList(antiAliasingOption));
    settings.setSearchBoxVisible(false);
    setCenter(settings);

    setOnShown(e -> {
        HBox rightBox = (HBox) settings.lookup(".secondary-graphic");
        rightBox.setPrefWidth(60);
    });
}
```

[image]

Another option is to override the default styling within your css file:

```
.settings-pane .options-grid > .option-row > .secondary-graphic {
    -fx-pref-width: 60;
}
```

Comment: `lookup` returns null. But i do see "secondary-graphic" in Scenic View. Any ideas why?

Comment: Yes, `lookup` has to be called when the scene is shown. That's why I'm using `View::setOnShown` to call it. I tested it on desktop.

Comment: Yes. I basically copy-pasted your code but my `BasicView` extends `View`.  And I added it to the MobileApplication with `addViewFactory`.

Comment: Same as mine, I am using a single view template. Try to print out if you have a scene before calling the lookup: `setOnShown(e -> { System.out.println("scene: " + getScene()); ... }`

Comment: It prints `scene: javafx.scene.Scene@615d9c6e`, so it's not null.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking for `".secondary-graphic"`(mind the dot)?

Comment: I found where the problem is but I don't understand why. In this view I also override the `updateAppBar` method. If I create an object in that method then the error occurs on the `lookup` line. e.g. add the line `Button okButton = new Button("OK");` in the `updateAppBar` method.

Comment: Still works for me. Run a new sample (Single View) just with the code above and check if it works for you. Then find out what's different in your code.

Comment: Well I don't know where the problem is. When I add another view all sorts of things like the above start behaving weirdly. Will try to sort it out. Meanwhile, there are 2 problems with this approach: 1 is that clicking next to the control (like in the red line area in my picture) will budge it back to the previous position. 2 is that it works only for the first option but not on others after it.

Comment: Probably the best approach will be using CSS. That will work for all the Options. Anyway, if you still want to use lookup, use `lookupAll` instead to find all.

Comment: The CSS is indeed more robust because even lookup all fails when clicking next to the controller. The CSS needs to be added also "onShown" or can I move it somewhere else?

Comment: It's also pretty odd that the `hgrow` on the middle component is ALWAYS and on the right is NEVER but it isn't obeyed. the middle doesn't take all the space leftover.

Comment: And I figured out the initial problem. In a multiview project, if this is not them main view, the first time it is switched to the lookups will fail. if i switch back to the main view and then to this one then the lookups will find. Can I run through all the views to initialize them before the app finishes loading?

Comment: By CSS I meant loading a stylesheet at the `postInit` method, just when you have your scene, and not using lookup/lookups. But if you want, you can also apply a css file for each view (if you are using a MultiView project with FXML you already have those files available and loaded). It is not a good idea to "initialize" the views.

Comment: OK. it appears that my real-world case is more complicated. I'll have to write a new question when I get to work on the finer details of the layout. Thanks for all the help meanwhile!